# How to get Onion v3 private key file from files generated by mkp224o?

Tags: onion-routing

I have genarated a castom onion v3 domain by using mkp224o
i got 3 file

1. hostname
2. hs_ed25519_public_key
3. hs_ed25519_secret_key

now  I need the private key file to upload it to the TOR host's server. I want to know how to proceed in detail to create the private key file from the 3 files.

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The secret key (`hs_ed25519_secret_key`) is the onion service's private key.

The `hs_ed25519_secret_key` file does not have an extension. You should add this file to your tor hidden service directory. This is often in `/var/lib/tor/`, but it depends on how you installed tor. You also need to make sure to set the correct permissions for this file. You will also need to set up the onion service in your torrc file. You might find this helpful for learning the directory structure: https://famicoman.com/2018/01/05/configuring-a-tor-hidden-service/

Comment: Hi, but how to creat a file to upload to the TOR host's server and what is the extension of that file?

Comment: The `hs_ed25519_secret_key` file does not have an extension. You should add this file to your tor hidden service directory. This is often in `/var/lib/tor/`, but it depends on how you installed tor. You also need to make sure to set the correct permissions for this file. You will also need to set up the onion service in your torrc file. You might find this helpful for learning the directory structure: https://famicoman.com/2018/01/05/configuring-a-tor-hidden-service/

Comment: Hi, I want you to know that I am not hosting the site on my pc but I will use a TOR host and for that I have to upload the private key file on it.

Comment: Okay I don't know what a Tor host is, but you should upload the `hs_ed25519_secret_key` file as that is the private key.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to upload the private key of my custom domain to the hoster below:             http://fhostingineiwjg6cppciac2bemu42nwsupvvisihnczinok362qfrqd.onion/signup/     do you understand what i mean now by private key file and tor hoster?

Comment: Okay I don't know anything about these services. You should contact them to ask for help. Maybe they want a v2 onion service key, which is deprecated and will be removed from the network in about 8 months.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that by uploading your hs_ed25519_secret_key to ANY third party hosting you're losing control over it.
Beauty of TOR is you can run your Hidden Service from your own hardware and be perfectly safe

Answer (score 0):

The secret key (hs_ed25519_secret_key) is the onion service's private key.
its a base 64 encoded file its easy to decode that go to the website https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file then select the file and click enter boom! u will get the string file into txt format i tried and it worked so yea u can check it out